# Why can't I use a port with my website domain name?

Tags: dns, port, iis-8

I have a registered domain name, www.aaaDomain.com, assigned to ip address xx.xx.xx.xx . I set up my site on IIS8 to use the ip address xx.xx.xx.xx and port 8020 for my website. I can connect to the website when I type xx.xx.xx.xx:8020 in a browser but I cannot connect to the website when I use www.aaaDomain.com:8020 
Also, I have another website on this same server as my Default website. When I type just the domain name without the port number, my default website comes up (because DNS does not allow adding port numbers) just like when I type in the ip address without the port number.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is what my site binding looks like on IIS8.
[image]

Comment: `I cannot connect to the website` - what specifically happens? Any HTTP status codes, or is the URL unresolved?

Comment: "The site can't be reached", "took too long to respond" ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: can you ping the domain name of the new website? if you can does it return the correct address, also did you remember to open port 8020 on your firewall?

Comment: When I ping the ip address, all request time out. When I ping the doman name, all request time out. When I set the site up, I did open the port in the firewall for both the server and in the Azure portal since it is an Windows Server 2012 in Azure.

Comment: Oh wait I was wrong. The port was not opened in the Azure portal. Which again is something I did not mention in my initial post. My apologies.  The site does work now because the port is open on both the server and the Azure portal.

Comment: Glad you managed to get it sorted, I've written it up as an answer for you to accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have an existing site running on the server you should check your security settings on both the Windows firewall and any other security/firewall settings you have - It sounds like you have not opened the additional port which you have just configured in IIS.

Check to see if you can ping the new site by its domain name - that will verify that you have the correct DNS setup, you can also try & browse to it via the server console (or remote desktop) if that works then its security setting somewhere blocking your access. Even if the ping request times out it should still resolve the name to an IP address for you to check. You may find that ICMP is also blocked.

Answer (score 0):

If you just changed your dns record, be aware that you should wait up to 72 hours for the dns to replicate after changing your dns record.

Comment: I have another site on that server as a Default webstie. When I type in the domain name without the port number, it goes to the default site just like if I type the ip address without the port number. I should have added that to my initial description of the problem. I will do that now.